# Finding the length of the shortest interger

Tags: javascript

I have been tasked with this question:

Simple, given a string of words, return the length of the shortest word(s).

String will never be empty and you do not need to account for different data types.

I wrote a code as follows:

```
function findShort(s){
  //var word = s.split(' ')
  var result = parseInt(word.map(a => a.length))
  return result
  return Math.min(result)
}
```

the output keeps bring the length of the first word instead of the shortest word.
What might be the problem?

Comment: The problem might be that you're parseInting an array. Also you're returning twice.

Comment: *"you do not need to account for different data types"*: so why did you decide to use `parseInt`? When do you think `Math.min()` will be executed?

Comment: Try a combination of `.split()` and `.reduce()`

Comment: two returns? `return result
  return Math.min(result)`

Comment: What is the expected length of _"It's lunch time."_ How do you handle contractions?

Answer (score 2):

`parseInt(word.map(a => a.length))` this will convert the result of `map()` into an integer, you don't want that.

Also, you can't return twice from the same function call, so the second `return` will never be reached.

[`Math.min()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) excepts multiple values as arguments, not an array, use the [spread syntax (`...`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to pass the values as arguments instead of an array

```js
function findShort(s){
  const word = s.split(' ')
  const result = word.map(a => a.length);
  return Math.min(...result);
}

const res = findShort('hello be world Foo');
console.log(res);
```

---

That said, you could also use `reduce()` to compare 2 words, and only  'keeping' the length of the shorter one:

```js
function findShort(s){
    return s.split(' ').reduce((p, c) => p < c.length ? p : c.length, Infinity);
}

const res = findShort('hello be world Foo');
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Minor wording improvement suggestion: "you can't have 2 returns" to something like "you can't return twice from the same function call" (because two `return`s is legal, and sometimes useful if one or more is conditionally executed, but any given call to a function can only result in a value from one of them).

Comment: Your final snippet is broken; it accesses `.length` of `p`, but `p` is always a number, not a string (it silently produces `undefined`, and ends up keeping the final length, not the minimum length). You want `return s.split(' ').reduce((p, c) => p < c.length ? p : c.length, Infinity);` (replacing `p.length` with just `p` since it's already a length, and using `Infinity` as the initial value because otherwise the result is always `0` (since `0` is the minimum possible length).

Answer (score 1):

Since apostrophes do not typically count toward the length of a word in most contexts, you should probably add an option to handle them.

I added a `prune` flag to the function to remove non-word characters when determining the length of a word.

```js
const findShortestWordLength = (phrase, prune = false) =>
  phrase.match(/\b\w+('\w+)?\b/g)            // Match all words (and contractions)
    .reduce((minLength, word) =>             // Reduce each word to a min word length
      Math.min(minLength, prune              // Store the min length
          ? word.replace(/[\W]/g, '').length // Remove apostrophes
          : word.length)                     // Keep the original in-tact
        , Number.MAX_VALUE);                 // Initialize with max; we want a min

// No pruning
console.log(findShortestWordLength("It's party time!"));       // 4
console.log(findShortestWordLength("It's a Wonderful Life!")); // 1

// With pruning
console.log(findShortestWordLength("It's party time!", true)); // 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply iterate but the thing here I believe is to what thing to initialize. Thinking about a little bit, You can discover You can need to initialize somewhere depending on how you are iterating the list. In my case, I decided to initialize with the first word. Also consider that by taking this approach, the searchWord function will return the first instance or match with the minimum length. You can then return an array of shortest words by pushing them into an array variable.

```
function searchWord(strings){
   let words = strings.split(' ');
   let min = words[0].length;
   let word=words[0];
   for (w of words){
     if ( w.length < min) {
         word = w;
     }
   }
   return word;
}

searchWord("aw ab abc d");
```

Answer (score 0):

Split and reduce!

```js
function findShortestWordLength(input) {
 const words = input.split(' ');
 const minLength = words.reduce((min,word)=>Math.min(min,word.length),Infinity);              
 return minLength;
}

console.log("The shortest word length is:",findShortestWordLength("One Two Three Four"));
```